# How to get a 1 bitdepth JPEG image

Tags: export, image

Make a test image

```
img = Binarize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Import[Export["test."<> #,img, "BitDepth"-> 1],"Summary"] & /@ {"jpg","png","bmp"}]
```

[image]

As you see, just the `JPEG` image fail to set 1 bitdepth. But this list show `JPEG` can have a option of `"BitDepth"`

```
Grid[{#, System`ConvertersDump`exportOptions[#]} & /@ {"PNG", "BMP", 
   "JPEG"}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> {1 -> Directive[FontSize -> 16, Red, Bold]}]
```

[image]

It is a bug of `Mathematica`? How to get a 1 bitdepth JPEG image

Comment: I would expect that `"BitDepth"` of `1` isn't supported by JPG, but this option probably allows setting higher `"BitDepth"`s.

Comment: The JPEG compression is designed for photos, or images with smooth gradients. It makes no sense to use it on binary images, so those are not supported.  There are 12-bit JPEGs, not just 8-bit, which may be the reason for the presence of this option.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Alexey Popkov So you think I should keep this post or delete it?

Comment: @yode The real question is, why do you want a jpeg compression for a binary image. PNG is far superior for those kinds of images.